# Elasticsearch query not returning correct data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, chewy-gem

I am using the [Chewy](https://github.com/toptal/chewy/) gem to integrate [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/index.html) into my Rails project.
I set up the index for a model called (`Listing`) and my search interface where I use the Chewy es dsl.

*listings_index.rb*

```
class ListingsIndex < Chewy::Index
  settings analysis: {
    analyzer: {
      exact: {
        tokenizer: 'keyword',
        filter: ['lowercase']
      }
    }
  }
  define_type Listing.available.includes(:listing_images, :user) do
    field :id, type: 'integer'
    field :listing_type, analyzer: 'exact'
    field :status, analyzer: 'exact'
    field :bedrooms, type: 'integer'
    field :price, type: 'integer'
    field :tenant_fee, type: 'integer'
    field :neighborhood_id, type: 'integer'
    field :bathrooms, type: 'float'
    field :lat, type: 'float'
    field :lng, type: 'float'
    field :available_date, type: 'date'
    field :full_address, type: 'text'
    field :title, type: 'text'
    field :user_last_active_at, value: ->(listing) { listing.user.last_active_at } # last_active_at on the User model is of type date
    field :street, value: ->(listing) { listing.street }
    field :listing_images do
      field :image, type: 'object'
    end
    field :coordinates, type: 'geo_point', value: ->{ { lat: lat, lon: lng } }
  end
end
```

*listing_search.rb*

```
class ListingSearch
  include ActiveData::Model
  attribute :bedrooms, type: Integer
  attribute :listing_type, type: String
  attribute :price_min, type: String
  attribute :price_max, type: String
  attribute :date, type: String
  attribute :neighborhoods, type: Array

  def index
    ListingsIndex
  end

 def search
   [base_filter, neighborhood_ids_filter,
    price_filter, date_filter, bed_filter, apt_type_filter, sorting].compact.reduce(:merge)
 end

 def sorting
   index.order({ user_last_active_at: :desc})
 end

 def base_filter
    index.filter(term: {status: 'available'}).limit(4000)
 end

 def apt_type_filter
   if !listing_type.blank? && listing_type =~ /\d/
     if listing_type == '1'
       index.filter(term: { listing_type: "full" })
     end
     if listing_type == '0'
       index.filter(term: { listing_type: "share" })
     end
   end
 end

 def bed_filter
   return unless bedrooms.present?
   index.filter(term: { bedrooms: bedrooms.to_i })
 end

 def date_filter
   return unless date.present?
   parse_date = Chronic.parse(date, {:guess => false}).first
   body = {}.tap do |body|
     body.merge!(gte: parse_date) if date?
   end
   index.filter(range: {available_date: body}) if body.present?
 end

 def price_filter
  return if price_min == 'Min $' && price_max == 'Max $'
  if price_min != 'Min $' && price_max != 'Max $'
    body = {}.tap do |body|
      body.merge!(gte: price_min.to_i) if price_min?
      body.merge!(lte: price_max.to_i) if price_max?
    end
  elsif price_min == 'Min $' && price_max != 'Max $'
    body = {}.tap do |body|
      body.merge!(lte: price_max) if price_max?
    end
  elsif price_min != 'Min $' && price_max == 'Max $'
    body = {}.tap do |body|
      body.merge!(gte: price_min) if price_min?
    end
  end
   index.filter(range: {price: body}) if body.present?
 end

 def neighborhood_ids_filter
   index.filter(terms: {neighborhood_id: neighborhoods}) if neighborhoods?
 end
end
```

The first problem is the filter `apt_type_filter`. It doesn't return the correct data.

The second problem is when I sort the data using the `sorting` method I get a ES BadRequest error:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [user_last_active_at] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"listings","node":"IYxQCcHESTWOaitD9XtDFA","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [user_last_active_at] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."}}]},"status":400}
```

Here's the output of Chewy's index `Query` object:

```
<ListingsIndex::Query {:index=>["listings"], :type=>["listing"], :body=>{:size=>4000, :query=>{:bool=>{:filter=>[{:bool=>{:must=>[{:bool=>{:must=>[{:bool=>{:must=>[{:term=>{:status=>"available"}}, {:terms=>{:neighborhood_id=>["45"]}}]}}, {:range=>{:price=>{:gte=>800, :lte=>3000}}}]}}, {:range=>{:available_date=>{:gte=>2018-02-01 00:00:00 +0100}}}]}}, {:term=>{:bedrooms=>1}}]}}}}>
```

Any help would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: You can get the actual Json request sent to ES by disabling direct streaming, then you can see the actual request and easier to spot the problem. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mohammad gave me good insight into the problem. To resolve it I changed two things:

First, I did not indicate to ES how `user_last_active_at` should be indexed so I specified the type of field to be indexed like so:

```
field :user_last_active_at, type: 'date', value: ->(listing) { listing.user.last_active_at }
```

As for the `listing_type` field  believe the problem was that ES was tokenizing the field value (splitting it into it's individual character). Rather my goal was to search on the full field value. Using the [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) to make it searchable

```
field :listing_type, analyzer: 'keyword'
```

Answer (score 1):

First Part:
you should be able to get elasticsearch's query from your ES client. It would help to debug why that filter doesn't work.
About the second part, what type your `user_last_active_at` should have? It is very good to have your mapping.
The error message says `user_last_active_at` is of string type in your index and hence you need to enable field_data for that field in your mapping (Look at [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html))

Comment: How can I get the query from the client? Isn’t that the last piece of code I provided in my question?  Also user_last_active_at is of type date

Comment: Take a look at here: https://github.com/toptal/chewy/issues/477. Seems you can use `render` function. Ok, then how do you define your mapping? your `user_last_active_at` has invalid type (text_ in your elasticsearch index.